# BASH regexp matching - including brackets in a bracketed list of characters to match against?

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to do a tiny bash script that'll clean up the file and folder names of downloaded episodes of some tv shows I like. They often look like "[ www.Speed.Cd ] - Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE", and I basically just want to strip out that speedcd advertising bit.

It's easy enough to remove www.Speed.Cd, spaces, and dashes using regexp matching in BASH, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out how to include the brackets in a list of characters to be matched against. [- [] doesn't work, neither does [- \[], [- \\[], [- \\\[], or any number of escape characters preceding the bracket I want to remove.

Here's what I've got so far:

```
[[ "$newfile" =~ ^(.*)([- \[]*(www\.torrenting\.com|spastikustv|www\.speed\.cd|moviesp2p\.com)[- \]]*)(.*)$ ]] &&
    newfile="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[4]}"
```

But it breaks on the brackets.

Any ideas?

TIA, 
Daniel :)

EDIT: I should probably note that I'm using "shopt -s nocasematch" to ensure case insensitive matching, just in case you're wondering :)

EDIT 2: Thanks to all who contributed. I'm not 100% sure which answer was to be the "correct" one, as I had several problems with my statement. Actually, the most accurate answer was just a comment to my question posted by jw013, but I didn't get it at the time because I hadn't understood yet that spaces should be escaped. I've opted for aefxx's as that one basically says the same, but with explanations :) Would've liked to put a correct answer mark on ormaaj's answer, too, as he spotted more grave issues with my expression.

Anyway, the approach I was using above, trying to match and extract the parts to keep and leave behind the unwanted ones is really not very elegant, and won't catch all cases, not even something really simple like "Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE - [ www.Speed.Cd ]". I've instead rewritten it to match and extract just the unwanted parts and then do string replacement of those on the original string, like so (loop is in case there's multiple brandings):

```
# Remove common torrent site brandings, including surrounding spaces, brackets, etc.:
while [[ "$newfile" =~ ([[\ {\(-]*(www\.)?(torrentday\.com|torrenting\.com|spastikustv|speed\.cd|moviesp2p\.com|publichd\.org|publichd|scenetime\.com|kingdom-release)[]\ }\)-]*) ]]; do
    newfile=${newfile//"${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"/}
done
```

Comment: Instead of `[- \[]` try `[-\ []` and instead of `[- \]]` try `[]-\ ]`.

Comment: Thanks, but no donut on either :(

Any thoughts on those? AFAICT, the first one escapes the space, and as for the second one, the BASH guide states that when using a dash as a literal (rather than to specify a range), it must come as the first character?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, this is the first time I've heard of the `=~` operator but nevertheless here's what I found by trial and error:

```
if [[ $newfile =~ ^(.*)([-[:space:][]*(what|ever)[][:space:]-]*)(.*)$ ]] 
                          ^^^^^^^^^^              ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Looks strange but actually does work (just tested it).

**EDIT**
Quote from the Linux man pages regex(7):

> To include a literal ] in the list, make it the first character (following a possible ^). To include a literal -, make it the first or last character, or the second endpoint of a range. To use a literal aq-aq as the first endpoint of a range, enclose it in "[." and ".]" to make it a collating element (see below). With the exception of these and some combinations using aq[aq (see next paragraphs), all other special characters, including aq\aq, lose their special significance within a bracket expression.

Comment: Indeed I forgot about that trick. It's mentioned in one of the first couple paragraphs of regex(7) of Linux manpages.

Comment: This one properly matches the closing bracket, including all spaces and dashes surrounding it! Thank you! Still has the first submatch eating the starting bracket though, but that's not a problem :)

Comment: Oh, I didn't bother with the subpatterns as I figured the real problem is the (seemingly) impossible escaping of those brackets.

Comment: *@aefxx:* +1, but you don't need `[[:space:]]` to match only a *space*. To match a space, it only requires that the space is escaped with a backshash `\  ` (because, unlike other regex environments, bash regular expression are exposed to the shell) ..

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you're doing a regex it's most compatible between Bash versions to put regexes in a variable even if you do manage to dodge all the pitfalls of putting them directly in a test expression. http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#if_.5B.5B_.24foo_.3D.2BAH4_.27some_RE.27_.5D.5D

Your current regex looks like you're trying to optionally match anything preceding the opening bracket. I'd guess you're actually trying to save for example 3 and 4 from something like this:

```
$ shopt -s nocasematch
$ newfile='[ www.Speed.Cd ] - Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE'
$ re='^.*[-[:space:][]*(www\.torrenting\.com|spastikustv|www\.speed\.cd|moviesp2p\.com)[][:space:]-]*(.*)$'
$ [[ $newfile =~ $re ]]
$ declare -p BASH_REMATCH
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH='([0]="[ www.Speed.Cd ] - Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE" [1]="www.Speed.Cd" [2]="Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE")'
```

Comment: Actually, as I've enabled case insensitive matching, the main problem seems to be my "zero or more instances" asterisk in subpattern two, so that the first subpattern will eat more than it should (because not having a starting bracket left uneaten still makes subpattern two valid). Your suggestion avoids that.

Comment: I was thinking of doing the same, i.e. matching anything not a starting bracket for subpattern 1, but wanted to be "more generic", and not demand the bracket to be there, as sometimes they'll just put in "- some.tracker.org" at the end or whatnot. But seriously, that's a corner case that I'll just have to live with :) OTOH, I still can't figure out why the pattern that is supposed to eat the right bracket and surrounding spaces and/or dashes isn't eating it all, neither in my code nor in yours (i.e. [4]=" - Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE, which I'd want to not have the leading " - ").

Comment: I'm gonna work on that now, but if you spot it, please let me know ;) Thanks!

Comment: Sorry to spoil but it is not the right answer: it would match "[ www.Speed.Cd\\ - Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE" for example. Notice the double backslashes?

Comment: That is because the [-[:space:]\\]]* part is not escaped correctly. Instead it is interpreted as either dash, space or backslash, then any amount of closing brackets. Since in your example the advertising ends with a space followed by a single bracket, the regex would match.

Comment: Thanks, edited to reflect all that. I just ditched the first grouping since it doesn't look like that needs to be saved at all correct? Now elements 1-2 should (I think) contain the right things.

Answer (score 1):

The basic issue is quite simple, if not obvious.
A BASH REGEX is *totally* unprotected (from the shell), and cannot be protected by **"**​double quotes​**"**.  This means that *every* literal space (and tab,etc) **must** be protected by a baskslash `\` ... end of story. The rest is just a case of getting you regex to suit your needs.

One other thing; use `[\ []` and `[]\ ]` to match   `[` and  `]` respectively, within the range square-bracket construct (in this case along with a space).

example:

```
newfile="[ ]"
[[ "$newfile" =~ ^[\ []\ []\ ]$ ]] &&
    echo YES ||
    echo NO
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this (though you weren't 100% clear on what cases you are trying to filter:

```
newfile="[ www.Speed.Cd ] - Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE"

if [[ $newfile =~ ^(.*)([^a-zA-Z0-9.]*\[.*\][^a-zA-Z0-9.]*)(.*)$ ]]; then 
    newfile="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}${BASH_REMATCH[3]}"
fi

echo $newfile
# Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE
```

Its just stripping any non-alnum (and dot) characters outside the `[]`, and anything within `[]`

Comment: @DanielSmedegaardBuus: The only range of characters I am specifying is those which would **not** be valid. Its a lot more open than the way you are hardcoding site urls

Comment: Sorry, @jdi, I missed your point. However, I'm specifically trying to remove specific urls in this particular notation, and even when your suggestion works for this particular case, it simply removes anything within brackets, and could really be slimmed down to "[[ $newfile =~ ^(.*)(\\[.*\\])(.*)$ ]]" AFAICT.

Comment: @DanielSmedegaardBuus: AFAICT they don't match the same. Consider "Some stuff here - [ www.Speed.Cd ] - Some.Show.S07E14.720p.HDTV.X264-SOMEONE"

Comment: either that, or the ^(.*) and (.*)$ parts are irrelevant... But you're definitely on to something, as is ormaaj, whose answer I'm currently trying to consume and test out. There's definitely a logical problem with my greedy first submatch, the ^(.*) part, as either way, it'll eat the first bracket, even if the second submatch looks for one. I guess I overlooked that I'm looking for ZERO or more instances of [, space, or - in submatch 2, so submatch 1, which is greedy will always eat the first bracket! :)