# Double square braces in Bash

Tags: bash

I need to match some variables defined in a config file against an input file in bash and replace the variable with config file input.

Config file

```
var1=value1
var2=value2
```

input file

```
My user value is [[var1]] and
some lines which does not have configuration variables
My client value is  [[var2]]
some lines which does not have configuration variables
```

var1 and var2 in line 1 and 3 above must be replaced by the value in config file 
rest of the lines remains same.

I am able to read config in an associative array say mapVals and input file to an array say inpArray.

Now when I am matching in a loop with below code.

```
for key in "${!mapVals[@]}"
do
        match=\[\[$key\]\]
        echo $match
        let index=0
        for line in "${inpArray[@]}"
        do
            if [[ $line =~ $match ]];
            then
                    echo $line
            fi
            index=$(($index+1))
        done
done
```

I am getting match for both line1 and line 3 for both of the [[var1]] and [[var2]] matches. 
the output looks like

```
[[var1]]
My user value is [[var1]] and
My client value is  [[var2]]

[[var2]]
My user value is [[var1]] and
My client value is  [[var2]]
```

What should be the way for an exact match and replace. 
Please comment if duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10183375/606202)

so for square braces we need to use escape  []

```
the regex for [[var1]] is => [\[][\[]var1]]
```